# Border messes up when using border-radius

Tags: html, css

Here is HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Smth:</td>
        <td>Lalala</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is CSS:

```
table
{
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

table td
{
    padding: 15px;
}
```

When I use border-radius and border together, it messes up.

Is it possible to correct that? (I can't show it in jsFiddle, because border-radius doesn't work there)

Comment: In wich renderer does it happen?

Comment: border-radius work on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/28p9W/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table {border-collapse:separate;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/seler/28p9W/